# ENS .eth names are secretly auctioned. Why is this name publicly visible during auction?

Tags: ens

Why is the name "newmovies.eth" [visible on Etherescan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5f01caf2dafd1b8f132179d1364ecedb53372331a0fae8c94832bb7e09d7de9a) in the `startAuctionsAndBid` public transaction with the ENS .eth Registrar?

It shows:

> ENS StartAuction for newmovies.eth

I thought that name is supposed to be secret and hashed. In this transaction it is not the case. I've tested with MEW ENS name auction creation and the name appears in clear in the test transactions. Anybody monitoring that kind of transactions can know the new auctioned names. Why aren't they kept secret and hashed?

Answer (score 2):

It's because it's an existing popular domain name / word:

> The DApp and the twitter bot have built in lists of common names, drawn from an English dictionary and Alexa’s list of top 1 million internet domain names. They use these lists to show you when common names are being auctioned. We do this because if the app didn’t reveal these names, anyone with a little technical skill could find them out anyway, giving them an advantage over those who don’t have the capacity to build their own list and code to check names against it.

Source: [ENS FAQ](http://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=common#how-do-the-dapp-and-the-twitter-bot-know-what-names-people-are-auctioning)

Comment: Well. people with a bit more technical know how are using this to snipe domain names. like this fella: https://etherscan.io/txs?a=0xa7f3659c53820346176f7e0e350780df304db179&p=1 

He has probably sniped and sold eth domains for a ton of money: https://etherscan.io/txsInternal?a=0xa7f3659c53820346176f7e0e350780df304db179